# The best way to find number of occurrences of word in string (C++, no spaces in string)

Tags: c++, string

Let's say you are given a string "banana".

You want to find out how many times "ana" can be found in "banana". So, that number is 2.

```
string s = "banana";
int num = 0,pos = 0;
pos = s.find("ana");
while(pos!=string::npos) {
    num++;
    pos = s.find("ana",pos+1);
}
cout<<num<<endl;
```

The thing is, I want to write shorter code for this. What functions can be used ? I tried using search() but it's not what I wanted. Count() is only for characters.

Are there any other functions that can help me with doing this ? (Boost is not allowed on competitions, so not this one).

Comment: This is about as good as you could ask for.  I suppose a you could use a regex to remove a line of code or two but regexes can be pretty heavy.

Comment: Competitions :) . what competitions? where? if you tell me I might not give you the answer but instead post it to the competitions for my self :)
Also shorter code does not necessarily mean faster program!

Comment: Competitions are country-level for pupils :/

Comment: Shouldn't it be like```pos = s.find("ana", pos + 2);``` since "ana" is what you are looking for not "nan" ?

Comment: I would be surprised if a competition permitted contestants to obtain outside assistance.

Comment: Your question is already asked. Check this one out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489073/counting-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string

Comment: I wanted to ask is there shorter way to do that ?

Comment: I think the best way in terms of speed would be to use [Boyer–Moore string-search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm). You search for the best way in terms of what?

Comment: @SomeName I wrote a new answer. If it solved the problem please consider voting/accepting it! (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that finally you intend to also count any possible replication of a phrase, here are 3 generic function templates which work for almost any container or pointer/array , providing that they are given the right first/last iterator instead of container!

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

//finding the occurrence for an specific case within a range
template<typename rng_t__, typename dif_t__ = typename std::iterator_traits<rng_t__>::difference_type>
dif_t__ occurrence(const rng_t__ rng_fst_, const rng_t__ rng_lst_, const rng_t__ schd_fst_, const rng_t__ schd_lst){
    dif_t__ counter = 0;
    for (rng_t__ it = rng_fst_; (it = std::search(it, rng_lst_, schd_fst_, schd_lst))++ != rng_lst_; ++counter);
    return counter;
}
//finding the replications for all subsets with certain length within a range
template<typename rng_t__, typename dif_t__ = typename std::iterator_traits<rng_t__>::difference_type, typename val_t__ = typename std::iterator_traits<rng_t__>::value_type>
dif_t__ replications(const rng_t__ rng_fst_, const rng_t__ rng_lst_, dif_t__ lnt_){
    if(!lnt_ or lnt_ >= std::distance(rng_fst_, rng_lst_)) return 0;
    rng_t__ it_lst = rng_fst_;
    for (--lnt_; lnt_--; ++it_lst);
    std::map<std::vector<val_t__>, dif_t__> cases;
    for (rng_t__ it_fst = rng_fst_; it_lst++ != rng_lst_; ++it_fst){
        auto it_rslt_pair = cases.insert({{it_fst, it_lst}, 0});
        if(! it_rslt_pair.second) ++(it_rslt_pair.first->second);
    }
    dif_t__ counter = 0;
    for (const auto& a_case : cases) counter += a_case.second;
    return counter;
}
//finding the replications for all subsets with all possible lengths within a range
template<typename rng_t__, typename dif_t__ = typename std::iterator_traits<rng_t__>::difference_type, typename val_t__ = typename std::iterator_traits<rng_t__>::value_type>
dif_t__ replications(const rng_t__ rng_fst_, const rng_t__ rng_lst_){
    const dif_t__ rng_lnt = std::distance(rng_fst_, rng_lst_);
    dif_t__ counter = 0;
    for (dif_t__ a_lnt = 0; ++a_lnt < rng_lnt; counter += replications(rng_fst_, rng_lst_, a_lnt));
    return counter;
}

#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    std::string range = "banana", searched = "ana";

    std::cout<< "total occurrence for the ana" << std::endl;
    std::cout<< occurrence("banana", "banana" + 6, "ana", "ana" +3) << std::endl;
    std::cout<< occurrence(range.begin(), range.end(), searched.begin(), searched.end()) << std::endl;

    std::cout<< "total replications for every phrase from banana with length of 3" << std::endl;
    std::cout<< replications("banana", "banana" + 6, 3) << std::endl;
    std::cout<< replications(range.begin(), range.end(), 3) << std::endl;

    std::cout<< "total replications for every phrase from banana with every possible length" << std::endl;
    std::cout<< replications("banana", "banana" + 6) << std::endl;
    std::cout<< replications(range.begin(), range.end()) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

possible output:

```
total occurrence for the ana
2
2
total replications for every phrase from banana with length of 3
1
1
total replications for every phrase from banana with every possible length
6
6
```

Good luck with the competition!

Answer (score 0):

> I want to write shorter code for this

You want to use `while (true)` and `break`:

```
std::string s{"banana"};
std::string::size_type pos{0};
int num{0};
while (true) {
    pos = s.find("ana", pos);
    if (pos == std::string::npos) break;
    pos += 2; // next possible place for an "ana";
    ++num;
} 
std::cout << num << "\n";
```

Comment: Is using ```while(true)``` and ```break``` really faster?

Comment: @AKL - only way to tell is inspect the assembly or measure the duration.

Comment: @2785528   Thank you for your wise,  broad and typical answer! what I really meant was, why should it be faster?

Comment: @AKL OP didn't ask for faster code, OP asked for shorter code.  This way uses only one line for `find`.

Comment: why should it be faster?  I don't know that it should.  My experience is that your desktop (and mine) is a complex system. The size or nature of the "code change" has no relation to "performance change".  The system is non-linear.

Comment: @2785528  what you are experiencing my friend, is CPU being warmed up during raising up their clock speed from different conditions. Also not to forget Operating systems change the hard-working core/s to avoid them being overheated. And what I meant was a significant change in speed at almost equal conditions! If one claims something is faster one should be able to explain it in term of logic or at least repeated experience!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop for this:

```
string s = "banana";
int num = 0;

for (auto pos = s.find("ana"); pos != string::npos; pos = s.find("ana",pos+1))
    num++;
cout << num << endl;
```

As you can see, I used `auto` as type for `pos`, so it will have the correct type `std::string::size_type`.

Comment: Thank you for repeating my answer! Would you also be willing to take a down-vote from @AlanBirtles too? :) First _ mine is even shorter! (i am talking about the code). Second _ you spend half of the amount of letters that you saved by using auto with repeating pos in finding and equality check!

Comment: Also why is every body using post-increment ```num++``` instead of pre-increment ```++num``` which is faster and has less overhead?

Comment: @AKL In my opinion it is the best solution regarding the readablitily and the shortness of the code. Also using `num++;` or `++num;` here will end up in the same assembler code: https://godbolt.org/z/GLwgEj

Comment: 1- since it is "readability" not "readablitily" I am not sure how good you can judge readability! 2- readability was not what the questioner asked for. 3-you guys are so obsessed with assembler and optimizer that became lazy. Although it might not matter in this case, nothing beats developing a good habit. 4- please go ask AlanBirtles to remove his down-vote:)

Comment: @AKL this isn't the same as your answer and doesn't have the same bug

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest code without sacrificing readability is something like this:

```
std::string s = "banana";
int num = 0;
size_t pos = 0;

while ((pos = s.find("ana", pos)) != std::string::npos)
{
    num++;
    pos++;
}
std::cout << num << "\n";
```

or as a for loop:

```
std::string s = "banana";
int num = 0;
for (size_t pos = 0; (pos = s.find("ana", pos)) != std::string::npos; num++, pos++)
{
}
std::cout << num << "\n";
```

Comment: Dude you were so obsessed with testing the "anana" case that you wrote it for the loop case. Since it was under 6 characters I couldn't edit it for you!

Comment: And speaking of different cases, there is a possibility(no matter how  much small) that ```std::string::npos```  is of an integer type of smaller/greater than the size_t and since it is usually filled with -1,  your code can also contain an infinite loop if one of string::size_type or size_t   is unsigned where one of them is smaller than int and the other is not. There is a reason why size_type is defined in string. Also should I start a Post on when to use post increment operators?

Comment: @AKL `std::string::size_type` is always `std:size_t`. Post increment operators are not generally more expensive for integer types, they only become (potentially) more expensive for structures like iterators, the compiler optimises away the difference

Comment: As far as my readings ```size_type``` in ```string``` is defined by the ```size_type``` of its ```Allocator``` and one can choose to use one other that default ```std::allocator```. But maybe I am wrong and not that I doubt you but only to be able to prove this to someone else if it ever happens, I would appreciate it if you could kindly provide me  a reference for "std::string::size_type is always std:size_t".

Comment: I agree with you about post increment operations, it is just about developing a good habit, not having double standards and readability of the code. Because of reading not authentic materials, I was not even aware of pre increment operator for a long time!

Comment: `std::string`'s allocator is always `std::allocator` who's `size_type` is `std::size_t`