# Finding all instances of a word in a string in C++

Tags: c++, string

So I am trying to make a program that gets an input from a text file, and has the user enter the term they want to search for. From there, the file should be printed out with 3 asterisks in front and behind all of the terms.

It works currently, but it only finds the first term in the file, I want it to find all terms. Any help?

Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int a, i, z, loc;
    string inputFileName;
    string s, term;
    ifstream fileIn;
    char ch;
    cout << "Enter the name of a file of characters: ";
    cin >> inputFileName;
    fileIn.open(inputFileName.data());
    assert(fileIn.is_open() );
    i = 0;

    while (!(fileIn.eof()))
    {
        ch = fileIn.get();
        s.insert(i, 1, ch);     //insert character at position i
        i++;
    }

    cout << s;
    cout << "Enter a word/phrase you want to search for in the file you entered" << endl;
    cin >> term;
    cout << "The word/phrase " << term << " will have '***' before it and after it" << endl;
    z = (int)term.length();
    loc = s.find(term);

    s.insert(loc, 1, '*');
    s.insert(loc+1, 1, '*');
    s.insert(loc+2, 1, '*');

    s.insert(loc+3+z, 1, '*');
    s.insert(loc+4+z, 1, '*');
    s.insert(loc+5+z, 1, '*');
    cout << s;

    return 0;
}
```

**Text output**
Enter the name of a file of characters: text.txt

Repair- Determined by the difficulty of the fix, and the parts needed in order for it to work.

Enter a word/phrase you want to search for in the file you entered

the

The word/phrase by will have '***' before it and after it

Repair- Determined by ***the*** difficulty of the fix, and the parts needed in order for it to work.

Comment: `using namespace std;` is [bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: @BaummitAugen It's a bad idea in headers which will be recombined in circumstances beyond your control, but even on the question you cite  [plenty of upvotes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1452759/211160) say it's to your discretion in private C++ implementation files.  And on stackoverflow it shortens many examples.  So don't bother calling people out unless it's demonstrably in a header, and even then...there are probably other things to worry about.

Comment: The formatting is terrible.  Please format your code so that others can read the code more easily.  FYI, my code formatter detected you have a missing brace somewhere, so your code isn't even compilable.

Comment: Whoops I had an extra brace in there. Fixed. Will reformat in a moment :D

Comment: I made an edit that fixes the formatting, but I don't think it's been reviewed yet

Comment: [`while (!f.eof())` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ## std::basic_string::find
>
> **Return value**
> Position of the first character of the found substring or npos if no such substring is found.

(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

This means you can simply loop `std::string::find` until its return value is `npos`, adding the previous substring location plus the substring length as the starting position.

As you also don't want to find words that contain the substring, but merely the substring as a standalone word, I've added some checks at the start of the function. **Note:** using a regular expression engine may be cleaner at this point.

```
loc = 0;

while ((loc = s.find(term, loc)) != std::string::npos)
{
    // check for space at start of term, or check
    // for beginning of string
    if (loc != 0 && s[loc - 1] != ' ') {
        loc += z;
        continue;
    }

    // check for space at end of term, or check for end of string
    if (loc != (s.length() - z) && s[loc + z] != ' ') {
        loc += z;
        continue;
    }

    s.insert(loc, 1, '*');
    s.insert(loc+1, 1, '*');
    s.insert(loc+2, 1, '*');

    s.insert(loc+3+z, 1, '*');
    s.insert(loc+4+z, 1, '*');
    s.insert(loc+5+z, 1, '*');

    loc += z;
    loc += 6; // the amount of asterisks added
}
```

There are also quicker ways to find all substrings, not using the C++ standard library. [This question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815838/how-do-i-find-all-the-positions-of-a-substring-in-a-string?) accepted answer contains one.

Comment: I did that^ but it froze up for some reason. It wont print out the new string after I added the while loop that you suggested above.

Comment: Oh, that might be because it's finding the same string over and over again, try changing `loc + z` to `loc + z + 6` (the amount of asterisks added) - my test program merely printed the substring, so I didn't have such a problem. (I'm just guessing here, you should really use a debugger like gdb to see what's going wrong)

Comment: Ahh, yes, that works now. But theres another issue that I found now. If you search for a term, and there is another word that has that term inside of it( "the", "e***the***rnet")

Is there any way to check for the ascii space value before and after the term?

Comment: You could add some logic that checks for a space before and after the term (and add exceptions for the beginning and end of the string) - I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Well Thank you!! I tried to upvote your post but i need 15 karma(rep)or something. :)

Comment: No problem :)
While you can't upvote it, I think you *can* accept it as a correct answer (although that might be after a certain time)

Answer (score 1):

string.find("term") gives you only the first occurrence of the term "term". 
If your file is not too long, one way to solve the problem is as follows.

```
int loc[100], i=0;
int pos = string.find("term", 0);
while(pos!=string::npos) {
   loc[i] = pos;
   pos = string.find("term", pos+1);
   i++;
}
```

string.find(term, pos) allows you to search for a term in a string on or after the index "pos".

Ofcourse you can create a dynamic array for storing more than 100 locations

Comment: forgot to increment 'i' in the loop

Comment: and that's why `std::vector<int>` should have been used instead in first place.

Comment: Agreed. Vectors make much more sense. The focus was on string.find(term, pos) though. Thanks anyway for pointing out :)